# Choice of PCB coil design for filter inductor at ca 20 to 400 MHz, 5 W

Tags: filter, inductor

Looking at the diplexer schematic from [this](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/16958/where-to-get-leaded-rf-capacitors) nice question,

[image: Diplexer schematic]

I realized this can completely be done in PCB-formed elements (minus the connectors). (As a kind of counter-action to the original question's intent to get leaded capacitors, I'm not only trying to eliminate the leads, but also the discrete components.)

- the 50Ω aren't actually resistors, they are the wave impedance of the cable / device you attach there
- a 20mm × 20mm rectangular plate capacitor formed by patches on the top and bottom layer of a 0.8mm thick piece of FR-4 ($\varepsilon=4.7\varepsilon_0$) is about 20 pF
- There's PCB coil designs that provice up to µH in inductance.

Now, assuming I don't plan to work with as high power as the original question, but still substantial power (5W) in a relevant range of 20 MHz – 500 MHz:

Would

1. a planar coil antenna 
   [image: planar coil, field normal to substrate]
2. a coil formed through alternating between layers (so that the main magnetic flux is inside the substrate)
   [image: PCB in substrate coil]

be most effective?

- I'm *told* (but I don't have access to the software to simulate that) that planars have low Q. I have no such information on the other choice.
- Which design has lower self-capacitance?

Comment: Marcus, glad that something good comes from my question. Would be very interested to see how it turns out and how you proceed. Any chance you'd care to document it somewhere?

Comment: Since all coils would be in the same plane, would that not lead (no pun intended) to too much coupling?